# How to populate DataGridView using Select with Where Clause using parameters.addwithvalue?

Tags: vb.net

Sorry for my noob question, But how can I add values in @id in a select command?

I'm using vb.net and MySQL

here is calling all the 'time' column, but I want to add a where in a query.
("Select time from dtr where id = @id") where will I put the parameters.addwithvalues command?

```
con = New MySqlConnection
        con.ConnectionString = "server = localhost; userid = root; password=; database=mjb_payroll; SslMode=none"

        Dim query As String = "Select time from dtr"

        Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand(query, con)
        Dim adpt As New MySqlDataAdapter(cmd)
        Dim tbl As New DataTable()

        adpt.Fill(tbl)
        DataGridView1.DataSource = tbl
```

Comment: There would be examples of ADO.NET using parameters all over the web. What exactly do you not understand about the examples you found when you searched?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your concern is just on adding `parameters.addwithvalue` you can add it after declaring your `MySqlCommand`:

```
    Dim query As String = "Select time from dtr where id = @id"
    Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand(query, con)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", id)
    Dim adpt As New MySqlDataAdapter(cmd)
    Dim tbl As New DataTable()
```